# Entity Framework Filtering On GrandChildren

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

Still pretty new to entity framework. So forgive me if this is a noob question. Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I am trying to select data from 3 related tables.

```
Leagues -> Teams -> Rosters ->
```

The relationships are `League.LeagueID => Team.LeagueID => Roster.TeamID`

In the Roster table there is a `PlayerID` column

I need a query that can select all leagues where Roster has `PlayerID = 1`

I cannot seem to filter results on the grandchild record no matter what I try. Not finding too much on the internet either.

I have found a way to do this with anonymous types but those are read only so i can make changes to the data. I must be able to update the data after it returns.

Comment: Please be considerate about double posting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.Leagues.Where(l => l.Teams.Any(t => t.Roster.PlayerID == 1));
```

The SQL generated should get you what you want, even it looks unreadable ;)

If you want to specifically use inner joins to do this, you can do so with code like this:

```
from l in db.Leagues
join t in db.Teams on l.LeagueID equals t.LeagueID
join r in db.Rosters on t.TeamID equals r.TeamID
where r.PlayerID = 1
select l
```

**UPDATE**

To do with with eager loading the child associations use `Include()`:

```
((from l in db.Leagues
join t in db.Teams on l.LeagueID equals t.LeagueID
join r in db.Rosters on t.TeamID equals r.TeamID
where r.PlayerID = 1
select l) as ObjectQuery<League>).Include(l => l.Teams.Select(t => t.Rosters))
```

Comment: this doesnt quite work. when i look at the sql it creates left joins and returns way too much data.  maybe i was being too simplicist.  what i really have is 4 tables.  

Parent -> Child  -> GrandChild -> GreatGrandChild

I want to return all the parents but filter on child and greatgrandchildren.

in other words

Select Parent* from Parent inner join Child inner join Grandchild inner join GreatGrandChild
where child.Column5 = 600 and GreatGrandChild.Column3 = 1000

Comment: added another option that does the query you want, does that help you?

Comment: this seems to work but  i have a question.

if i do this
foreach (var league in l)
{
   foreach (var team in league.Teams)
   {
      foreach (var roster in team.Rosters)
      {
      }
   }
}

will eachof those inner loops make a call to the db?  i was hoping to bring all this data back at once to cut down db trips.

Comment: What you want is called eager loading - updated to include this.  With eager loading, calling `foreach` won't trigger a database hit, since the items are already loaded into the association collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Roasters.Where(r=>r.PlayerId ==1).Select(r=>r.Team).Select(t=>t.League).Distinct()
```

If Roaster has many teams and team has many leagues you can use `.SelectMany` instead of `.Select`

Example of `.SelectMany` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
PetOwner[] petOwners = 
                    { new PetOwner { Name="Higa, Sidney", 
                          Pets = new List<string>{ "Scruffy", "Sam" } },
                      new PetOwner { Name="Ashkenazi, Ronen", 
                          Pets = new List<string>{ "Walker", "Sugar" } },
                      new PetOwner { Name="Price, Vernette", 
                          Pets = new List<string>{ "Scratches", "Diesel" } } };

                // Query using SelectMany().
                IEnumerable<string> query1 = petOwners.SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);
```

Comment: this may work but having trouble with SelectMany.do you have an example?

Comment: It should be the same syntax, try .SelectMany in stead of .Select

Comment: just replacing Select with SelectMany in your example does not work. compile error

Comment: That might mean it doesn't have multiple records on the other side.

Comment: is a compile error.  there is no way the compiler will not there is not multiple records on the other side without running the app.

Comment: It does, you'll have to have IEnumerable as the property when you use SelectMany

Comment: sorry, not sure what i am doing wrong. they are definetly lists and the complier doesnt like it if i just switch Select for SelectMany