# Entity framework. Need help filtering results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filtering

Need to select data in entity framework but need to filter on the childrent and grandchildren

i have  4 tables. `Parent -> Child -> GrandChild -> GreatGrandChild` I want to return all the parents but filter on child and greatgrandchildren.

in other words (for example)

```
SELECT     Parent.* 
FROM       Parent 
INNER JOIN Child      
INNER JOIN Grandchild 
INNER JOIN GreatGrandChild 
WHERE      child.Column5           =  600   AND
           GreatGrandChild.Column3 = 1000
```

it cant be anomymous type because i need to update the data and saveChanges to the db.

using vs 2010 and EF 4.0

Comment: in your example sql, i assume there should be join criteria?  i.e.  `Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID`.

Comment: Please be considerate about double posting.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524030

Comment: yes there is join criteria i just didnt put that in for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @DexterMorgan in some cases brevity can hurt the question or cause people to think you are missing more concepts than your question implies. You either end up with potentially incorrect assumptions or comment threads like this :)

Comment: sorry, this is what im trying to accomplish. these are the real tabls and the real SQL that would produce what i want

SELECT     Person.* 
FROM       Person P
INNER JOIN Plan PL ON P.PersonID = PL.PersonID     
INNER JOIN Coverage C on PL.PlanID = C.PlanID
INNER JOIN CoveredMember CM on C.CoverageID = CM.CoverageID
WHERE      CM.TermDate = NULL AND PL.PlanType = 1

Comment: this seems like it should be so hard to accomplish with EF but it appears so.

Comment: @DexterMorgan I think you have 3 complete solutions below, all of which would work.

Comment: 2 dont work for reasons i stated in each of them.  the only one that remotely works is the one directly below (select q1).
my question about that one is that it does filter the way i wanted it to but it only brings back records for the parent table.  if i do loops to get to the grandchildren
   foreach (var q2 in q1)
                    foreach (var q3 in q2.q3s)
                        foreach (var q4 in q.4s)

wont that make a db call with each iteration?

ideally i would like to make one call to the db and have the full object tree all the way to the grandchldren

Comment: so if you take my sql from above instead of Person.*  i would like to really have Person.*, Plan.*, Coverage.*, CoveredMember.* from ......

Comment: You are getting into several other concepts here around how your navigation properties are set and lazy loading, which are separate issues from your original concern. Further, there may be ways to reduce the calls to the DB for multiple entities into a single roundtrip, but I doubt that is necessary, and you are losing some of the advantages to using EF in attempting to do so. Basically, solving the number of round trips you are making likely has more to do with how EF and your navigation properties are configured at this point than it does with your query.

Comment: i understand what you are saying and not trying to argue with you but if i bring back 500 persons who have medical that is not termed 
then i have to loop thru all of them to bring back the plans for eaach one that is 500 calls.

then if i have an inner loop in there to bring back the coverages for 500 plans and each plan has say 2 coverages that is 1000 more calls. then if i have to go to the covered person ..... you get the point.  so i do think it is necessary to avoid 1000s of db calls.  seems like i the sql statement i supplied above is pretty simple. are you saying EF cant do this?

Comment: this is pretty disappointing that this question cant be answered. i think this may be a shorting coming of EF and maybe not even worth using if it cant handle something as simple as this.

Comment: What I am trying to say is you have separate questions here: Your first was how to bring back the parent entity based on conditionals on the children. In the comment thread you have added additional requirements on retrieving other entities in the same SQL call. This is possible, but a seperate concern altogether. You could start by reading / understanding Lazy/Eager loading: http://codingatilivedigitally.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading/

Comment: Also, there are times where you work around EF for performance reasons, or perhaps use a reverse navigation property, or possibly a read-only entity on a view depending on your needs. All of this is a question with much wider scope than was asked / answered here. I wouldn't give up on EF, but in places where you have performance issues it may require additional work to get around. Finally: make use of the SQL Server (or other DB) profiler to see what EF is actually doing with your requests. They may not be as expensive as you think (or are sometimes much more so than you would expect).

Comment: yes i agree i didnt state my question right the first time and i do appreciate your help.  but yes what i need is to retrieve additional RELATED entities in the same call. i have read and understand lazy/eager loading but learn much better with examples.  maybe what i am asking is not possible and i am ok with that but if there is a way to do it, i dont see a soltution here that actually works, i dont even see anyhwere on the internet this is done.  like i said i can do the filter and get the columns i want if i use anyomounous types but those are read only.

Comment: SELECT Person.*, Plans.*, Coverages.*, CoveredMembers.* 
FROM Person P 
INNER JOIN Plan PL ON P.PersonID = PL.PersonID 
INNER JOIN Coverage C on PL.PlanID = C.PlanID 
INNER JOIN CoveredMember CM on C.CoverageID = CM.CoverageID 
WHERE CM.TermDate = NULL AND PL.PlanType = 1

i want to accomplish exactly what that query does. each table is a one to many relationship to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linq you should need something like this.

```
var q = from q1 in dbContext.Parent
        join q2 in dbContext.Children
        on q1.key equals q2.fkey
        join q3 in  ........
        where q4.col1 == 3000
        select q1;
```

Comment: You're missing the joins here and assuming there is only one of each of the children.

Comment: Not really, the joins are made by the navigation properties, the ones I'm using. If there are multiple children the list will have multiple records. You can then use .Distinct()

Comment: i have tried this but i cant seem to get to the GrandChild.  after o.Child i type the dot and Grandchild is not an option. There is a one to many relationship set up on these tables.  i am sure its me that is doing something wrong. any suggestions?

Comment: maybe i should mention that parent can have many children > childrent can have man grandchildren > grandchildren can have many greatgrandchildren

Comment: @MiguelMatos in your case, with the navigation properties, o.Children would be a list and would not have the GrandChildren property (each entity of the list will). I don't believe EF would support an implicit join like this does it?

Comment: @Matthew, I'm not sure, I have to test it, but what you are saying makes sense.

Comment: he is right.  o.Children is a list and does not have a GrandChildren property

Comment: @Dexter Morgan I added a linq version of it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @MiguelMatos I think you have it now.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do what you want. Yes, it is a bit of a mess because it is so deeply nested.

```
var result = context.Parent
                    .Where(parent => parent.Child
                                           .Any(child => (child.Column5 == 600) &&
                                                          child.GrandChild
                                                               .Any(grandchild => grandchild.GreatGrandChild
                                                                                            .Any(greatgrandchild => greatgrandchild.Column3 == 1000))));
```

Comment: parent.Child.GrandChild does not work because Child is a list.
in my above comments i explained that parent can have many children. each of those children can have many grandchildren each of those grandchildren can have many greatgrandchildren

Comment: @DexterMorgan The way he has this written it should work as well, just missing the extra GreatGrandChildren table.

Comment: The query does not contain `parent.Child.GrandChild`. ;) And there is no need to deal with `GreatGrandChild` because they are neither retrieved nor used to constrain the result.

Comment: My fault - I used `GrandChild` instead of `GreatGrandChild` because I misread the question. Updating my answer.

Comment: this does not work.  the ANY produces outer joins which return way too much data.  i am a little disappointed at the EF that this is so difficult.

this is my real world example
Person > Plan > PlanCoverage > CoveredMembers each person can have many plans. each plan can have many coverages. each coverage can have many CoveredMembers. i want to apply a filter on Plan.PlanType = 1 and coveredMember.TermDate = null this should return all Persons who are in a medical plan that is not terminated. i would like to return the parent and all children (all the way to the coveredmember)

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure - if your example is not just for illustration, leads me to think you may want to think more about your model here (i.e. are children separate entity types or should they be a defined relationship?)

What you describe is a simple joins and where clause though, and is written essentially the same way: assuming you are returning DBSet from your DBContext:

```
_context.Parents.Join(context.Child, p=>p.Parent.ID, c=>c.ParentID)
.Join(...Grandchild...).Where(o=>o.Column5=600)
.Join(...GreatGrandChild...).Where(o=>o.Column3=1000)
```

**EDIT** to get back the strongly typed entities you might need to do something like:

```
var greatgrandchildren = context.GreatGrandchildren.Where(o=>o.Column3=1000).ToList();
var grandchildren = context.Grandchildren.Where(o=>o.Column3=600 and greatgrandchildren.contains(o)).ToList();     
var children = context.Children.Where(o=>grandchildren.Contains(o)).ToList();
var parents = context.Parent(o=>children.Contains(o).ToList();
```

My syntax might be off, and someone can add, can I avoid .ToList() to prevent roundtrips until the last call?

Comment: the children must have a parent. but a parent can have many children.

same with the grandchildren. must have a child but a child can have many grandchildren

same with greatgrandchild.  the model is proper and relationships are set up properly

Comment: Which this join will work for - there is a miss to your last requirement: trying to remember how to return just parent objects here.

Comment: What I meant by the relationship table is would this not be better as a people table with an additional table which defines the relationship between people? Does your model ever need to support a people changing places in the hierarchy? I.e. adding Great-great-grandchild requires an additional table, or for a child to have a great-grandchild does that mean they would both exist in the child and the parent tables?

Comment: i would actually like access to the whole object tree if that makes sense.

i was under the impression that in Entity Framework. i can return the parent and all the children and the children with grandchildren etc..  from the database (while applying that filter). is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: no, never need to change places.  those arent the real names of the tables i jut thought that was the easiest way to describe it.

Comment: Person > Plan > PlanCoverage > CoveredMembers

each person can have many plans. each plan can have many coverages. each coverage can have many CoveredMembers.

i want to apply a filter on Plan.PlanType = "medical" (really an enum) and coveredMember.TermDate = null

this should return all Persons who are in a medical plan that is not terminated.

i would like to return the parent and all children (all the way to the coveredmember)

Comment: This is definitely a common thing to do with EF, just slightly more complex than the basic query.

Comment: doesnt seem so stragight forward to me but im pretty new at EF.  any example of this would be appreciated.

Comment: your edited code may work (havent tried it yet) but i would like to not make multiple calls to the db which ToList() will do.

Comment: var greatgrandchildren = context.GreatGrandchildren.Where(o=>o.Column3=1000).ToList();
is not very efficient.  

in my real world example this woudl be
CoveredMembers.CoverageTermDate = null.

this would be bring back about 500K records.
what i need is that filter and a filter on Plan
where is 2 levels up

Plan.PlanType = 1 AND CoveredMember.CoverageTermDate = null

this way only termed plans of plan type 1 would come back which would be far less than 500K

Comment: I think you can drop the .ToLists until the final call and end with a single query.

Comment: this does not work at all.  anybody have a solution? is this THAT complex?

Comment: Note - the dropping .ToList() should work if you are returning IEnumerable / IQueryable from the repository. Then a call will only be made when you actually call ToList on the final resultset. I would want to pay attention to how good a job EF does in translating that query though.