# entity framework 4.0 multiple joins

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is my real world example.
I have 4 tables:

- Person
- Plan
- Coverage
- CoveredMembers

Each person can have many plans, each of those plans can have many coverages. Each of those coverages can have many CoveredMembers.

I need a query that will apply a filter on `Plan.PlanType == 1` and `CoveredMembers.TermDate == null`.
This query should bring back any person who has a medical type plan that is not terminated.

This SQL statement would do just that:

```
SELECT Person.*, Plans.*, Coverages.*, CoveredMembers.* 
FROM Person P 
INNER JOIN Plan PL ON P.PersonID = PL.PersonID 
INNER JOIN Coverage C on PL.PlanID = C.PlanID 
INNER JOIN CoveredMember CM on C.CoverageID = CM.CoverageID 
WHERE CM.TermDate = NULL AND PL.PlanType = 1
```

I have figured out how to do this using anonymous types, but I sometimes need to update the data and save back to the database - and anonymous types are read only.

I was given a solution that did work using JOIN but it only brought back the persons (albeit filtered the way I needed). I can then loop through each person:

```
foreach (var person in persons) {
  foreach (var plan in person.Plans{
    //do stuff 
  }
}
```

But wouldn't that make a db call for each iteration of the loop? I have 500 persons with 3 unterminated medical plans each, so it would call the db 1500 times?

This is why I want to bring the whole data tree from Persons to CoveredMembers back in one shot. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is accomplished in two parts:

1. Your query to determine the people you wish to have returned based on your criteria as discussed in this question previously: [Entity framework. Need help filtering results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524879/entity-framework-need-help-filtering-results/14524972#14524972)
2. Properly setting the navigation properties for entities you want brought together to be eagerly loaded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

For example if your Person entity looks like:

```
public class Person {
   public List<Plan> Plans {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

When returning data from the dbcontext you can also use explicit eager loading with the `include` option:

```
 var people = context.People
         .Include(p => p.Plans)
         .ToList();
....
```

If these are nested  - coverage is part of plan, etc (which it looks like, it goes something like):

```
 var people = context.People
         .Include(p => p.Plans.Select(pl=>pl.Coverage).Select(c=>c.CoveredMembers)))
         .ToList();
....
```

I am making some assumptions about your data model here, and my code above probably needs a little tweaking.

**EDIT**:

I might need someone else to weigh in here, but I don't think you can add the where clause into an include like that (my example above leads you that way a bit by putting the include on the context object, instead return an IQueryable with your conditions set as solved in your first post (without a ToList() called on it) and then use the code you wrote above without the Where clauses:

From first post (you supplied different criteria in this one, but same concept)

```
 var q = from q1 in dbContext.Parent
    join q2 in dbContext.Children
    on q1.key equals q2.fkey
    join q3 in  ........
    where q4.col1 == 3000
    select q1;
```

Then:

```
List<Person> people = q.Include(p => p.Plans
  .Select(pl => pl.Coverages)
  .Select(c => c.CoveredMembers).ToList();
```

Again, doing this without being able to troubleshoot - I am sure it would take me a few attempts to iron this one out too.

Comment: i appreciate the help. this is pretty close i think.  i can do the eager loading with the includes but when i try to add the filters it errors, mostly likely cause im not very good at the syntax so im sure im just doing it wrong. i am still kind of new to EF so forgive me.  this is what i got. can you point out what i am doing wrong?

'var people = context.Persons
.Include(p => p.Plans.Where(pl => pl.PlanTypeID==1).Select(pl => pl.Coverages.Select(c => c.CoveredMembers.Where
(cm => cm.TerminationDate == null))));'

Comment: sorry new to this site dont know how to format the code nicely on here :(

Comment: i think its getting very close, just it isnt bringing back the right amount of results.  i have a query i KNOW for sure is correct and it is bring backing 5004 results.  when i do this in EF it only brings back 1314 results.  i am looking at the generated sql and its way more complex than it needs to be but the where clauses do seem to be correct.

Comment: At this point if it is returning the results in the way you desire (i.e. eagerly loaded) it will be tougher to determine where the queries are differing. Can you post the actual (current) SQL and full linq queries you are now using? When I run into this (and I have :) I typically simplify both queries and ensure I am getting the same data, then add the join and so-forth until I determine the point of divergence.

Comment: I had one columns in a join wrong.  when i corrected it it now brings back 8800 rows. too many this time.  i did mark your answer correct because im pretty sure its working correctly just not sure why the sql is not returning the proper results.

Comment: got it working correctly but the performance is horrendous. its not even usable. when i run the query it produces in query analyzer it take about 2 secs to run.  it takes over a minute in EF.

Comment: Interesting... 8800 records coming back, several layers deep? It could be the bottleneck is the data transfer and object instantiation - but really a minute seems excessive. Is it getting it accomplished in a single query, or does it end up with several round trips?

Comment: actually this is not correct. i see why now. when i run the first query (the joins) in query analyzer i get exactly what i asked for. all the people with plantype = 1 and coverageTermDate = null. i verify the results wtih my own query.

then the next query runs with all the includes.  it is the same people but all the filtering is gone.  termed plans are in the results and other plan types.  once you do the include it loses all the filtering.  there has got to be a way to do this correctly but im beginning to think EF is not all its hyped to be.

Comment: the results are 5004 which is correct, i had another bad join i didnt see right away so it was 8800. once i corrected in the first query it was correct. but as i stated it loses its filtering when you run the Includes.  just to be clear i am running the sql generated by EF in query analyzer and getting these results and watching on SQL profiler

Comment: it is getting accomplished in a single query. i am taking the generated sql separately for each one though with ToTraceString()  and running them separately.  all in all the only real problem (and its huge) is its losing the filtering in the child tables when it combines these two statements. there has got to be away to do the includes and filter in the same statement, no?

Comment: looking more closely at the sql that is generated with the includes, it doesnt seem correct at all (besides not filtering). its doing a left outer joins.  this is not correct at all as all joins should be inner joins.

Comment: I think we are nearly at the place where you might want to ask yet a third question on tuning the query as you state in the last point on your comment. We are beyond what I think I can help with without hands on. Someone with more EF experience than me might have a good answer at this stage. Also on EF - generally ORM's are less useful when you are returning massive amounts of data at one time as there is overhead which can become too expensive.

Comment: On the inner / outer joins this seems by design: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c00d47b8-c686-4e9f-825c-d4ffb78ee7bd/ not sure the consequences of this. Honestly, I am using using EF to take advantage of the lazy loading as opposed to trying to return all data in this way (Just developed a search function for a site too which is the first time I really made use of includes, and even then not this aggressively).

Comment: i get what your saying and typically i wouldnt be bringing this much data back but i will always be using these tables  with filters on each of them. and i think the amount of data is irrevelant at this point.  filtering on child tables and bringing back the entire object tree (whether 5000 records or 5 records) seems like it is not possible.  this is a very simple sql statement to write by hand and if EF cant do this then i think it is not very good and not all its hyped to be.  i do appreciate all your help.

Comment: I would hesitate to blame EF - likely you and I are the issue :) In the end I would have really expected the query we ended with to work - surprised the logic is failing - again I think I am likely missing something in how I provided it.